# Does anyone know how can i make this outline part transparent or no fill

Tags: windows-10

Mine its colored,how can i make it transparent or no fill.

[That's how mine looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulEA3.png)

[That's how i want to make it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAtFO.jpg)

Comment: What exactly is it you want to change? The account picture?

Comment: Please edit your original question to add more details and explain your problem rather than reposting the same question

Comment: Even with the pictures I can't figure out what you're trying to do.